# WHERE IN clause with multiple values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to select items from a table when any values from a list appear in an array in the table.

list_id_array is an array of ids, identifying which lists an item is included in. The integers are individual list ids that I'd like to compare against the array for each row, matching when any of the integers are included in the list_id_array.

Here's a working example with one value:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE 
1163650 IN
UNNEST(list_id_array)
```

This works as desired. However, I would like to check for multiple ids.  For example, in addition to 1163650 I might want to also check for 654321 and 123456 and select items which includes any of those values in the list_id_array.

So, an example that does not work which might better describe what I'm looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE
/*any of the below*/
(1163650, 123456, 654321) IN
UNNEST(list_id_array)
```

How can I do this? I did my own searching, but had trouble finding anything that wasn't referring to multiple values in the parameter after IN rather than before.

Comment: You sure this is MySQL and not Postgres?

Comment: Sorry, it may be Postgres. My company has a system to use multiple dialects or query engines and I'm new to SQL so I'm not certain.

Comment: `1163650 = any(list_id_array)` would be more efficient than `1163650 IN
UNNEST(list_id_array)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [overlaps operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE)

```
where array[1163650, 123456, 654321] && list_id_array
```